# Return typings for dynamic functions

Tags: typescript, function, types, dynamic

I have a function whose only logic is to execute a function that is passed in.

```
const funcRunner = async (func: Function) => {
   return await func()
}
```

I know that whatever the response of the function that is passed in will be the response of this same function.

However, this function return signature is inferred as `Promise<any>`. Is there any way to keep the response type of the original function?

```
const bool = async isExample(): Promise<boolean> => true;

// result should be boolean, not any
const result = await funcRunner(isExample);
```

Comment: That doesn't look right: `const bool = async isExample(): Promise<boolean> => return true;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a generic type to run function:

```
type Runnable<T> = () => Promise<T>;
```

And then apply it for your `funcRunner`

```
async function funcRunner<T>(runnable: Runnable<T>): Promise<T> {
  return await runnable();
}
```

Optionally you can use inline typing:

```
async function funcRunner<T>(runnable: () => Promise<T>): Promise<T> {
  return await runnable();
}
```

Example usage:

```
async function example1(): Promise<number> {
  return 1;
}


funcRunner(example1)
    .then((result: number) => console.log(result))
```

Comment: Thank you, for my needs I simplified further to `const funcRunner = async<T>(func: Function): Promise<T> => {}`

Comment: @myol - The problem with that is that `Function` is incredibly broad, so you get no warning at coding-time if you're passing a function with required parameters to `funcRunner`, which doesn't provide any arguments when calling the function: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzMASksBTATjAvDAQwgE9kAeAFQBoA+ACkWQC4YAxJYKAS3AEoWAClhABbLhAyUaeaQG8AUDCUwsGKAixhCAdwJdYjYHV4BueQF8z8oqWDwO3cDAwAPAiIAOAGwwBGOgQsYAgiAEbYVDChLNBYXGAA5rwwCsoqahpaAMpQcYkByQDUUWbm8vIBJMgwxjIpisqgkLAEeDp6BhxoYJhYdK7u3n6mMAD0ozBkuNMwWQAWIAheACZRGIRa2MJYFrzGJkA

Answer (score 1):

You can make it generic, so TypeScript can infer from the call site, and use the utility type [`ReturnType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) to get its return type:

```typescript
const funcRunner = async <FuncType extends () => any>(
    func: FuncType
): Promise<ReturnType<FuncType>> => {
   return await func();
};
```

Usage example:

```typescript
async function example1() {
    return 1;
}

async function example2() {
    return "a";
}

(async() => {
    const result1 = await funcRunner(example1);
    //    ^? const result1: number
    const result2 = await funcRunner(example2);
    //    ^? const result2: string
})();
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=1&pln=21&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzMASksBTATjAvDAQwgE9kYAeAMSWABViAHDGDADygzABMIYAKAJR4AfITDFhfAFAxZ8GgC4Y1ZPSZSBSgApYQAWwCWEDORQYoCLGDUmVdRhmGjcogN4zZWc5bCEA7gQGsIjIggDcUgC+EVJEpMDyyFAG4CysBHoMADYYAIyCMO5yMF4WVjC5EZFSsSRkIcDJqWwZ2RgATAVFcqU+MABEBP1VNXxxoUIuhR6yoJCwXhAIWVC5eP6BwTRoYJhYfC2ZObkCEcUA9OfFAHoA-DMwc9AlGEsr7esEAUGJqOjYB3SRw6pwelxu90iAnCUiAA)

If you like, you can make `funcRunner` slightly more general-purpose by not making it `async`, and then it could run either `async` or non-`async` functions without adding a promise to the non-`async` ones:

```typescript
const funcRunner = <FuncType extends () => any>(
    func: FuncType
): ReturnType<FuncType> => {
    return func();
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzMASksBTATjAvDAHgDElgAVATwAcMYMAPKDMAEwhgAoBKPAPhgCGYCrw4AoGJPikAXDBLJKNMVzkoMUBFjBKMxUrv65+AbwlSsGrWGnJuAbjEBfR2IEQKyW8CgBLcHT0AgC2VAA2GACM3DBmUjCWmtowkY5OYm4eXojIfgEMIeEYAEwxcRZWyQBEAlVpGTk+-jYFoREAzGXmkonWMAAsxfViHO6ewDHGsd0woJCwlhAIYVCReIIA7gK+sI1oYJhYHK1FkVyO8QD0l-EAegD8M3PQCRhLK8XrAls73vuHxyCbRK5xm1zuj3izwWb2WUHa6z26GwgMKHXOMHBBFwOJgADkQDAAAbfbZQIkwTAYFjUmABKAAC187HAGDBNykD2cXAcYiAA)

You may not want to do that if you want to be sure to see `funcRunner` in the async stack trace, but if you're not bothered about that, you're good.

---

Just for fun: If you wanted to let `funcRunner` call functions that expect parameters, you can add an `args` argument that's fully typed:

```typescript
async function funcRunner<FuncType extends (...args: any[]) => any>(
    func: FuncType,
    args: Parameters<FuncType>
): Promise<ReturnType<FuncType>> {
    return await func(...args);
}
```

If you want to make that second argument optional for functions that don't take any parameters, I think you need to overload it:

```typescript
async function funcRunner<FuncType extends () => any>(
    func: FuncType,
): Promise<ReturnType<FuncType>>;
async function funcRunner<FuncType extends (...args: any[]) => any>(
    func: FuncType,
    args: Parameters<FuncType>
): Promise<ReturnType<FuncType>>;
async function funcRunner<FuncType extends (...args: any[]) => any>(
    func: FuncType,
    args?: Parameters<FuncType>
): Promise<ReturnType<FuncType>> {
    if (args) {
        return await func(...args);
    }
    return await func();
}
```

Usage examples for the overloaded one:

```typescript
async function example1() {
    return 1;
}

async function example2() {
    return "a";
}

function example3() {
    return Math.random() < 0.5;
}

function example4(num: number) {
    return num * 42;
}

(async() => {
    const result1 = await funcRunner(example1);
    //    ^?
    const result2 = await funcRunner(example2, []); // <=== Args is allowed even when optional...
    //    ^?
    const badResult1 = await funcRunner(example2, ["x"]); // <=== ...but it can't have anything in it
    //    ^?
    const result3 = await funcRunner(example3);
    //    ^?
    const result4 = await funcRunner(example4, [3]);
    //    ^?
    const badResult2 = await funcRunner(example4); // <=== Error as desired, need args!
    //    ^?
    const badResult3 = await funcRunner(example4, ["x"]); // <=== Error as desired, wrong type!
    //    ^?
})();
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=50&ssc=1&pln=18&pc=1#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsLyVASkiAUwCcAeAMRwBUwAHQmQgD2UIgBMQYAKAShgC8APhjAIYIdwBQMWdmgAuGJWg16AGim8lABWLoAtqhCFSuQsgTEIa0yqi2hQgNxTQkWIhQYsXvARIKajoGZlYOLm4AOhjgYgBzECUxMABtAF1+YVFxSRk5PyV7W005UQSkmB044AMLEhAg1RChLV19IxMzCysbEKaHFpc3cGh5KDRMcfwIIjJikMYWNk4eGKi4xOTxDKyRFLyywuVgjXzZTZAAfl0autZiRoX6Vu0qjuNTc0trWwHHEQAb3OMFQcB4l34wLKZWIPWsogA7sBUMhxtFYhVeK4ygBfEFwn5YYDI1Ho7FSfEjDzjSZYZi1WgAG0IAEY+DBoXJCb0YKzXFT3GM-HSloyWQAmDlc2Q8hEAImA8oFUikIp8YoMzMIAGZpQT4VgALLAZAACyixDE7EMHNIMAADFEAKwqtU4UUMrUsgAs3AgCAMSgDBgARiQoQaiTAQzAAFQwH0St3cIVQDnZGUwKCYEBouEgBBM5CswRIlFovwzObcL3a1kUsoAeibZQAelcQTmIHmYAWi8gJWWSRXpgFiLWmOLCBL1DBds4YC2YKQBGuYABBCqgrjAJlM9CIwjsRgANzYMERZov6FodL36xBy7kHa7ubRoeA7HMheLpYE5ZklW46TtOs7zvKTDypki7Lqu67rKGCBomSUBiAA5GiZrAOeORgOaqAQPEoJYKiT6ti+nZlN2vb9sWOrDqSlY4NWJCgd6uqNnIz6yK+1Hvn2hC-sgPqMaOwGzGxda+nOqQ6jB5HtlRcg0R+X4-gOQ4ASOQEsSB0mED62JLq28EAQAosQ+jEKIXDsEJqBwuwc5EMe5SJAAhIplFvj2anfkJA4MdpTFjpJE4GT6smQdBxlwWuFlWegNmgDA9kgI5x5zoi+hETAyAhF5zYUbxna4rwfCuEAA)

And of course, you can always make that one `async`-neutral as well; [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABKSAlcYCmAnAPAMXAgBUBPAB00UwA8pMwATAZ0QAoBKRAXgD5EAhmFK82AKESTkRAFyJCkMpQA0YjnNSYoIbGCWYCRfbwDcYlNHhIL6MFjwKSFKrXpNWbAHTeB2AObMckKkANoAulx8gsKiElIWco76qlKC-oGIAAq+AgC2WjjMhorOvGoaWjp6zsVOlKbmRLAI0mgYOLX61HQMLOzenr4BQcLhkfzBsakJ8kbOKVJDzAD8ctnYeQXYRUml5Yia2rr6naWIAN5xkjDA7Etcl6mp2JW6rRBePukcZqkAvldEC8jtYiJwzACxAJmKRIO9mkhaHlyAAbTAARk4F0BwKqiHRELEUJhcIsCO6yLRACYsY8pLi3gAiASMwmNSDkpG5VGYADMtJxryQAFkBFAABaeDZMOC5LG4RAABk8AFY2WSrBTuWiACxsMAgXJyA25ABGOAegpBiBNiAAVIgdVS2WxobCPuNsakIAhmFAgZhmCAUVB0TxBAB3AQwf02drYNhcnnon6AgD0adSAD1loCfWA-QGgyGqeGBFGY+9bPZEzRKZgqcpEGMTIgM4hcNwu4gAILpRAwVgCFEouARzCMagANwYiAj4tncHICOHA3TmakObzvv9poEjE0xdDZYrsaI1ZwtfrjebjJojIirfbne7A1NIH9lYgQgA5P7xQIM7RKQEowGAfgDkgMbrtmubejuRbBlAvLhnGdiXkmaK8qmqTtpucFSPmhYvEeOqoee8ZXtqmA6k2IS8o+MH4duBa7vuh5IaW3CRtGZ5tOhCaYTRPxtpmL7cQAotg2BwNggisIwgYwC8jBNlgE5pAEACETGSFu8GsYge4HoGSEodx5a8VWlFCbRt73o+okdl2knSbJ8mIIpzDKROTYRjJ4GIFAzg6bhG56bmfwcOCYhAA).

Comment: But now the result will *always* be a promise, which may not be desirable. In this case, you shouldn't need to `return await`, and therefore shouldn't need the `async` modifier, right?

Comment: @vera. - I figured they had a reason for making `funcRunner` an `async` function (and `return await ___` isn't always pointless -- it helps avoid gaps in the async call stack). But I think you're right that it would make sense to at least mention that it would be possible for `funcRunner` to be transparent in that way. I'll go ahead and do that.

Comment: @vera. - Done, thanks for flagging that up!