# Return type from function that takes a function as a parameter

Tags: typescript

I did a bad job at asking this question earlier, thought I had the answer, but ended up not having it.

I've created a [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwPICMBWBTYsC8MDeAUDDAIYBcMAjADTEwqUBMhAvmRDKJFIYVAgAOGGAFlSg4QCcAYgFcw2AJbgYeADwAlAHwAKUlIDmlAcJAAzeMnRYoASjXaYmwt2gwlAEwxgoSgWow+kaUpGAIDjhOBoZ8brCI8op+qni6cBLSlOKSGLIKyqke3r7+EY7wmXnp1pjYdnHg7lAAFhgAaqQANnIYSOYAgoGJBSlgurr4pKyR0Q3xMK0d3b39AwAKPRAAQsMISYXjk6Q0KDMVpADUKA0kQA) with the example code.

I'm looking to create a function (A) that takes a mapping function (B) as a parameter. The return value of A depends on the return value of B. I'm not sure how to type this.

```
const myObject = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
} as const

type MapperFunction = <R>(arg: typeof myObject) => R
const identity = (arg: any) => arg

const myFunction = (mapper: MapperFunction = identity) => mapper(myObject)

const theValueOfA = myFunction(({a}) => a)
const theValueOfAPlusB = myFunction(({a,b}) => a+b)
```

The above doesn't work because I get errors about R, which makes me think I should be using infer instead of generics, but I'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: I'm struggling to figure out which of these types is meant to be part of the solution and which are part of the example use case, could you clearly separate them for us? in particular I'm confused about `myFunction`'s types relying on the type of the `myObject` object...? Are all cases where `myFunction` will be used based on `myObject`?

Comment: FWIW, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75282830/157247) I show how to use the `Parameters` and `ReturnType` [utility types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#handbook-content) to create a generic function that accepts a function to run and arguments to run it with and returns the function's result. That seems closely related to what you're trying to do, if it helps.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - that answer is very useful in this case, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can just pass through the generic:

```js
const myObject = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
} as const

type MapperFunction<R> = (arg: typeof myObject) => R
const identity = (arg: any) => arg

const myFunction = <R,>(mapper: MapperFunction<R> = identity) => mapper(myObject)

const theValueOfA = myFunction(({a}) => a)
const theValueOfAPlusB = myFunction(({a,b}) => a+b)
```

Then the TS-compiler infers the types correctly.

Comment: Incredibly close! I think it's because I got the identity wrong in here as well. If the user doesn't supply a default parameter, I just want to return the full object. And if I do `const theFullObject = myFunction()` - then it's telling me `theFullObject` is unknown. Any ideas?

Comment: Actually, I know I can do this by just making the param optional, and omitting identity entirely, so I think this works!